# Opening .jar files with `pkexec` and using Desktop Entries to run commands

Tags: ubuntu, java, desktop-environment, lubuntu, pkexec

I am writing a bash script that automates installation of [TLauncher (Minecraft launcher)](https://tlauncher.org/en/) and basic dependency management on USBs running Lubuntu 18.04.

Part of the bash script creates a desktop entry under `/usr/share/applications` for easy launch from the Lubuntu menu.

Here is the entry I am using:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY /usr/bin/java -jar -Dswing.systemlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel ~/.minecraft/tlauncher.jar
Icon=~/.minecraft/icons/default.png
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Minecraft
GenericName=minecraft
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Game
```

The command `pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY /usr/bin/java -jar -Dswing.systemlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel ~/.minecraft/tlauncher.jar` works and does launch TLauncher if run in the terminal. However, I feel I am missing something when I put the command in the Desktop Entry.

When I try to open the entry from the Lubuntu menu, the cursor shows that something is loading, but then nothing happens no matter how long I wait. I am also not sure how to debug the Desktop entry. I tried to`xdg-open` the entry, but I got no output in the terminal and nothing happened either -i.e, TLauncher did not launch.

I tried putting the command in a separate bash file that looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

pkexec env DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/me/.Xauthority /usr/bin/java -jar -Dswing.systemlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel ~/.minecraft/tlauncher.jar
```

Running that in the terminal `bash testscript.sh` works and does launch TLauncher.

But when I put it in the desktop entry replacing the `exec` from the entry above like so:

```
Exec=/bin/bash /path/to/testscript.sh
```

It does not work.

The shell scripts have the proper permissions.

I feel like either I'm writing the Desktop Entry's `exec` value wrong or that `pkexec` isn't supposed to work from a Desktop Entry the way I am trying to make it work.

I would like to be able to launch TLauncher from a desktop entry via the menu and have a gui popup asking for the password in order to have the command run as `root`.

**Edit:**

Using full paths instead of `~` also yields the same result -i.e, it does not work and the above issues remain.

Setting `Terminal=true` does not solve this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Current solution: Since the command works when run in the terminal, simply have the Desktop Entry run the command with a terminal:

```
Exec=lxterminal -e "pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY /usr/bin/java -jar -Dswing.systemlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel /home/me/.minecraft/tlauncher.jar"
```

**Notes:**

I think I could build off of this to make sure that when the launcher is closed, it is actually closed as I noticed through `ps aux` that processes aren't actually being killed the way I expect causing strange behavior the next time I open the launcher.